# Google Adwords Conversion Code creates white space?

Tags: html, google-ads-api

I put the google conversion before the ending body tag but this creates a 30px tall white space under my footer on any site I put it on.

I think wrapping the code in a hidden div tag would work to rid the space but would the conversion code still run?  Why would a script tag create a space anyways?

Answer (score 0):

The space is intended for the Google Site Stats privacy notification. See the "Security and privacy" section of [this Adwords support article](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722022?hl=en).

You can alter this behavior by modifying the `google_conversion_format` variable of the conversion script. If I remember correctly, setting this to `"3"` will prevent the Google Site Stats box from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by hiding the conversion script code inside div tags like this.

```
<div style="display:none">
  <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- conversion code -->
  </script>
</div>
```